# Marshmallow imageButton selectableItemBackground

Tags: android

In marshmallow devices, ImageButton doesnt appear to show that it's being clicked. Tested in kitkat devices and it's working fine.

I've tried using `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` for `android:background` but it doesnt seem to work.

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/add"
  android:padding="5dp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_check"
  android:tint="@color/grey"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```